# remove add new post, if there is already one post

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-customizer

I have a custom post type, but I want to allow only one post. if the user posts then the add new post should should be disabled or removed. so only post is allowed of that custom post type. If the one post is deleted, then the add new should be visible

I have tried removing the label Add new in the custom post type, but it appears even when not declared. I believe wordpress by default adds ;add new to posts

Comment: Why not make this a "Page" instead of a CPT, then you can define what metaboxes and fields to show up on that specific page.

Comment: the plugin i have written is using custom post type. and im worried that it might take a long time to change it to page. or I might face new issues. I am kinda a novice in wordpress so it would be better to find a fix for it

Comment: Generally, finding a "fix" for something that might be a bad idea in the first place is an even worse idea. Please explain what your post type does and why it needs to be a post type instead of an ordinary page.